# best way to loop through list of arrays in react

Tags: reactjs

I made a const with some data and i wanna show it on my webpage like this:

name

- conf
- conf
  name
- conf
- conf
  name
- text
- text

To create this i made a list with data which looks like this:

```
  cities: [{
                name: "New York",
                conferences: [
                    "conf 1", "conf 2", "conf 3", " conf 4"
                ]
            },

            {
                name: "Amsterdam",
                conferences: [
                     "conf 1", "conf 2", "conf 3", " conf 4"
                ]
            },

            {
                name: "Paris",
                conferences: [
                     "conf 1", "conf 2", "conf 3", " conf 4"
                ]
            }

ettc
```

what is the best way to get this in react ?

```
    return (

        <div className="card">
   
            {content[0].cities.map((name) => {
                return <li>  {name} </li>
            })}

        </div >
    )
```

i tried it like this, but it is not working

Comment: Consider adding react code in the question.

Comment: i edited the react code!

Comment: With your cities data how you want your UI to look like . The sample output which you have added is not clear .

Comment: When you are mapping over `cities` you will get each `city` object back. In your code, you are naming that city object `name`. Instead, rename it to `city` and access the name property by doing `city.name`.

Comment: what should be the value for conf, conf name and text you want to show? I get  name should probably be the city name, but what should be conf, confname and text? The array with conferences only show conference names it seems

Comment: Maybe you want to destructure the `name`, use `content[0].cities.map(({name}) => {`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array#map` to iterate through each city and and then iterate through each conference.

```js
const {useState} = React;

const Conferences = () => {
  const [cities, setCities] = useState([{ name: "New York", conferences: [ "conf 1", "conf 2", "conf 3", " conf 4" ] }, { name: "Amsterdam", conferences: [ "conf 1", "conf 2", "conf 3", " conf 4" ] }, { name: "Paris", conferences: [ "conf 1", "conf 2", "conf 3", " conf 4" ] }]);

  return (
    <div className="card">
      {cities.map(({name, conferences}) => {
         return (
          <div>
          {name}
          <ul key={name}>
            {conferences.map(conf => <li>{conf}</li>)}
          </ul>
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </div >
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Conferences />,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
   return (
    <div className="card">
        {content[0].cities.map((city) => (<li>{city.name}</li>)}
    </div>
)
```

When you map over an array you will receive each complete item in that array, in your case a city object.

Answer (score 0):

```
content[0].cities.map((city) => {
                return ( <>  
                               <li>  {city.name} </li> 
                               {city.conferences.map((conf , index) => (<li key={index}>{conf}</li>)}
                              </>
            })}
```